# Wicket header contribution vs. metadata in html

Tags: java, wicket

I used Wicket 6.6.0 and upgraded to 6.14.0. In WicketApplication I have the following code within the init()-Method

```
getHeaderContributorListenerCollection().add(new IHeaderContributor() {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 442899940490126649L;

        @Override
        public void renderHead(final IHeaderResponse response) {
            response.render(WicketUtils.composeMetaItem("X-UA-Compatible", "IE=edge"));
            response.render(WicketUtils.composeMetaItem("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=UTF-8"));
            response.render(WicketUtils.composeMetaItem("Expires", "0"));
            response.render(WicketUtils.composeMetaItem("Cache-Control", "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0, private"));
            response.render(WicketUtils.composeMetaItem("Pragma", "no-cache"));
        }
    });
```

Which renders metadata in the html head.

This causes, after the update to Wicket 6.14.0, the Wicket Debugger to throw an Error after I do an ajax request. The error is not thrown if the above code is removed.

The Error is the following:

```
ERROR: Error in parsing: This page contains the following errors:error on line 22 at column 8: Opening and ending tag mismatch: meta line 0 and head
```

Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

Would it be possible to put the above metadata in HTML and what would be the difference?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<wicket:head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0, private">
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">   
</wicket:head>
...
</html>
```

Comment: I think you should downgrade to .13 and report this as a bug. Minor version patches should not have this kind of impact unless the changelog states otherwise. You did check the changelog, right?

Comment: Hi, this happend also when i upgrade from 6.6.0 to 6.7.0. I did check the changelog from 6.6. to 6.7. but nothing major which I come across.

Comment: Workaround is to manually put the meta tags in a global template shared by all your pages of course. You should still report it.

Comment: Is your mentioned workaround the one which I showed at the bottom of my post?

Comment: Oh, yes indeed it is. Jebus I read too quickly, I thought that was a dump of the HTML output. But now I spot the wicket:head tags. That's how I do it in any case, I try to keep as much of the view related logic in the actual templates.

Comment: Thank you a lot. I will put it in my html template. and still post it as a bug. Will see waht the reults will be

Answer (score 0):

In *Wicket 8* (as well as 7 and 6.17+), it's possible to add meta tags with [MetaDataHeaderItem](https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/8.x/org/apache/wicket/markup/head/MetaDataHeaderItem.html) in the following way:

```java
public class BasePage extends WebPage {

    @Override
    public void renderHead(IHeaderResponse response) {
        super.renderHead(response);

        response.render(MetaDataHeaderItem.forMetaTag("X-UA-Compatible", "IE=edge"));
        response.render(MetaDataHeaderItem.forMetaTag("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=UTF-8"));
        response.render(MetaDataHeaderItem.forMetaTag("Expires", "0"));
        response.render(MetaDataHeaderItem.forMetaTag("Cache-Control", "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0, private"));
        response.render(MetaDataHeaderItem.forMetaTag("Pragma", "no-cache"));
    }
}
```

It will produce following output:

```
<meta name="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta name="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="Expires" content="0" />
<meta name="Cache-Control" content="no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0, private" />
<meta name="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
```